# Etymology of Latin suffix -ālis

Tags: etymology, latin, indo-european

What is the etymology of the Latin suffix "-ālis" (and related forms like "-āris") as in "nātūrālis"? Do we know any corresponding suffix in other Indo-European languages?

Comment: Yes: _-al_ and _-ar._ English has borrowed extensively from Latin, as [this dissimilation puzzle shows](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Latin_dissimilation.pdf).

Comment: I'm sorry it wasn't clear: I'm aware of "-al" and "-ar" in English. I just wanted to follow the etymology further back in time if it's known.

Comment: It may well be cognate to a Germanic suffix in /l/ or /r/; generally these stay around in IE, but they often dissimilate with each other, as in Latin or Sanskrit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Part of the info in this answer is from Buck's *Comparative Greek and Latin Grammar*, which, though old and outdated in many respects, is probably still reliable on this point.)

Ultimately, Latin -āli-(s) goes back to a PIE suffix *-lo-, with reflexes in many branches.

Latin -āli- is originally the suffix -li- added to a-stem nouns: e.g. *animā- : animālis*. It became analyzed as a single, productive suffix, however, and was extended to other types of stems: e.g. *mort- : mortālis*.

This -li- is the same suffix seen in adjectives like *similis, humilis*, etc. But it seems to have been originally *-lo-: compare the Greek cognates of these words, ὁμαλός, χθαμαλός. Transfer of adjectives into the i-stem class was pretty widespread in Latin (not just from o-stems but also from other stem types, cf. e.g. *suāvis*: Gk. ἡδύς).

As for PIE *-lo-, its reflexes form participles in Slavic and Armenian, and are also found less productively but still commonly in Greek (see the examples above and many others, e.g. φῦ-λον, τυφ-λός), Sanskrit (e.g. *bahu-lá-* 'abundant'), and probably other languages.