# What's the function of the PIE suffix *-lo-?

Tags: proto-indo-european

I've seen it used sometimes, what was its purpose? Was it used to make adjectives describing relations to nouns as in Latin (where it transformed into -ālis, which works that way), or was it different?

Comment: Do you remember any specific words where it was used?

Comment: Oh, I found another question about it. I hope the following is helpful to you:  [Etymology of Latin suffix -ālis](http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/7122/etymology-of-latin-suffix-ālis)

Comment: Here is a paper discussing it: [The Indo-European adjectival class with the suffix *-lo- and its development in Slavic (2014). Journal of Indo-European Studies](http://www.academia.edu/9778408/The_Indo-European_adjectival_class_with_the_suffix_-lo-_and_its_development_in_Slavic_2014_._Journal_of_Indo-European_Studies)